# Identity Server with Entity Framework can't authenticate

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to setup client_credentials grant type in identity server 4 using the entity framework project.

I am using a sample config file to populate the database: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Config.cs

This data is entered into the database and I attempt to connect to the token endpoint via Insomnia, here is a screenshot of my setup:

[image]

It states invalid_client but I am not sure why, I ran a SQL profile and every time I hit this endpoint its running:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x.Properties].[Id], [x.Properties].[ClientId], [x.Properties].[Key], [x.Properties].[Value]
FROM [ClientProperties] AS [x.Properties]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP(1) [x8].[Id]
    FROM [Clients] AS [x8]
    WHERE [x8].[ClientId] = @__clientId_0
    ORDER BY [x8].[Id]
) AS [t7] ON [x.Properties].[ClientId] = [t7].[Id]
ORDER BY [t7].[Id]',N'@__clientId_0 nvarchar(200)',@__clientId_0=N'client'
```

It's trying to perform a join on the ClientProperties table, but this table is currently empty. I am not sure if this is the problem or not.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you `INNER JOIN` two tables, of which one is empty (as you state), the result set will always be empty so when the client can't be retrieved by client_id, you get "invalid_client".

Putting some data, linked to your client, into it should resolve the issue.